# Inject several objects in C++ ctor

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a good way to somehow dynamically inject several objects to main class and adjust its method by calls of these dependencies, e.g.

```
ComponentClass1
{
   updateSmth1();
};
ComponentClass2
{
   updateSmth2();
};
...
ComponentClassN
{
   updateSmthN();
};
```

And for now I need to change ctor and update method everytime I am adding new component like:

```
MainClass
{
   MainClass(ComponentClass1 &cc1, ComponentClass2 &cc2, ..., ComponentClassN &ccN);
   void update()
   {
      updateSmth1();
      updateSmth2();
      ...
      updateSmthN();
   }
};
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve that?
Thank you!

Comment: Can your basic components inherit from a common base that could provide updateSmt() as virtual function ?  Or are the component classes completely unrelated ?  And do youhave to provide your components at construction or would it be acceptable to add them dynamically in a second step ?

Comment: They are completely unrelated and adding them dynamically in a second step would be a perfect fit but i didn't find a good solution. For now I unified all my components to one master component to not change at least ctor definition every time i add a component. Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have an interface with an `Update` method, like `UpdateableComponent`. Make your components inherit that interface and pass a `List` of `UpdateableComponent` to your ctor. Then, in the `MainClass`'s `update` function all you have to do is iterate on your components and call `update` for each one.

Comment: These update methods are just not that similar and should not be called in a loop (there is some logic for theirs calls), that's why it wasn't working solution for me. My last thought was to try to apply visitor pattern to make my component list extendable. Will see how it works

Comment: double dispatch (visitor pattern) solves a different problem. It solves the problem of moving update logic into the components based on the class it was passed to (MainClass).  However, you'd still have to pass all the components to MainClass to get a *this pointer.